# why sometimes a function that has parameters inside its definition but in the actual function does not have any?

Tags: haskell

This is the piece of code that I am trying to understand

```hs
data Day = Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun

isWeekend :: Day -> Bool
isWeekend Sat = True
isWeekend Sun = True
isWeekend _ = False

isWeekday :: Day -> Bool
isWeekday = not.isWeekend
```

If I am trying to evaluate isWeekday Mon (I specified an argument of type Day from the function definition even if the actual function does not have it), it works. If I am modifying the isWeekday into isWeekday day, I have the following error: Couldn't match expected type `Bool' with actual type` Day -> Bool'.
Could somebody please tell me why I have to skip the parameter which has the type Day?
Thank you!

Comment: This code works for me. `isWeekday day` and `isWeekday` are fundamentally different, as the latter introduces an extra argument.

Comment: `not . isWeekend` *produces* a function.

Comment: Functions are not special at all, they are values like integers or booleans. We can write `x :: Int ; x = (expression evaluating to an Int)` in the same way as we can write `f :: Int -> Int ; f = (expression evaluating to a function Int->Int)`, e.g. `f = \x -> x+3`. In your case, `not . isWeekend` is an expression of type `Day -> Bool`, so it type check. In a sense, the "exceptional" form of definition is `f y = (expression using y to produce an Int)`, not `f = (expression producing a function Int->Int)` which is more basic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the reason that `not . isWeekend` has type `Day -> Bool` is because `not . isWeekend` will *return* a function. A key aspect of functional programming is that functions are "first class citizens": you can pass functions as parameters, and return functions.

Since `(.)` has type [**`(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:.), and `not` has type [**`not :: Bool -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:not), this means that `not . isWeekend`, or more canonical `(.) not isWeekend` thus has type:

```
(.) :: ( b   ->  c  ) -> ( a  ->  c  ) -> ( b  ->  c  )
not ::  Bool -> Bool
isWeekend ::              Day -> Bool
--------------------------------------------------------
not . isWeekend ::                         Day -> Bool
```

This expression this will *return* a function that takes a `Day` as parameter and returns a `Bool`.

You can write a version of `isWeekday` with a parameter:

```
isWeekday :: Day -> Bool
isWeekday day = not (isWeekend day)
```

But then you thus can not define this as <s>`isWeekday2 day = not . isWeekend`</s>, since then it means that `day` is a "useless" parameter, and it will still return a function, so then the signature is `isWeekday2 :: a -> Day -> Bool`.